# How can I load the .adf files in the google map or arcgis map . Do I need convert them?

Tags: android, google-maps, kml, shapefile, arcgis-js-api

How can i load the .adf files in the google map or arcgis map . Do i need convert the .adf files to shape file or kml file and how do i convert them?

I tried to convert the .adf file to kml in https://mygeodata.cloud/converter/adf-to-kmlsuperoverlay  but it showing the error

> No spatial data were recognized in your uploaded data. We are sorry.
> Make sure you have uploaded all relevant files of the dataset.

Answer (score -2):

To load .adf files into either Google Maps or ArcGIS, you'll need to follow a specific process that involves converting and preparing the data for use. .adf files are typically associated with ESRI's ArcInfo GRID format, and you'll need to convert them into a more common geospatial format like Shapefiles, GeoJSON, or other formats that can be used in both Google Maps and ArcGIS. Here's a general outline of the steps:

Convert .adf to a Compatible Format:

Use ESRI software like ArcGIS Desktop or ArcGIS Pro to convert .adf files to a format like Shapefile or feature class.
Alternatively, you can use open-source tools like GDAL (Geospatial Data Abstraction Library) to convert .adf to other formats. For example, you can use the gdal_translate command.
Example (converting .adf to GeoTIFF):

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff input.adf output.tif
```

Upload Data to ArcGIS (if you want to use ArcGIS):

If you want to use ArcGIS, upload the converted data (Shapefile, GeoJSON, or any other compatible format) to your ArcGIS Online or ArcGIS Enterprise account. You can do this through the ArcGIS Desktop software or ArcGIS Online interface.
Create a Web Map in ArcGIS:

If you're using ArcGIS, create a web map within ArcGIS Online or ArcGIS Enterprise.
Add the uploaded data to your web map as a layer.
Share the Web Map:

Share the web map publicly or with specific users if needed.
Embed in Google Maps (if you want to use Google Maps):

To display this data on Google Maps, you can use the Google Maps JavaScript API. You'll need to write code to integrate Google Maps with your data from ArcGIS.
You can overlay your data on Google Maps using custom markers, polygons, or other map elements by following the Google Maps API documentation.
Access Data in ArcGIS:

If you're using ArcGIS, you can access your data through the web map URL provided by ArcGIS Online or ArcGIS Enterprise.
The key here is to convert the .adf files into a format that can be used in both Google Maps and ArcGIS, and then you can take different paths depending on whether you want to display the data primarily in Google Maps or ArcGIS.

Comment: can you provide the one  example to how to do it. and provide one sample .adf files so that we can able to convert it to other format for checking purpose